# Lower bound 3-dimentional linear programming

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm reading [Computational geometry book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540779736).

In exercise   4.9 of the mentioned book we encounter the following problem:

> Suppose we want to find all optimal solution of 3d- linear programming with $n$ constraints. Argue that any algorithm for solving this problem have lower bound $\Omega(n\log n)$.

I try as follow: i think  we can construct a reduction from 3d convex hull to this problem, such that extreme points of intersection of half-spaces  is our optimal solution.
And because of we must count all optimal solution due to lower bound $\Omega(n\log n)$.
But i think my argument isn't true. Any help to verify my argument can be appreciated.

My second argument:
Suppose over linear programming have no objective function, and all extreme points are our solution, and according
‪Michael  [Ben-Or theorem](https://dccg.upc.edu/people/vera/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/cotasnuevas.pdf) counting number of extreme point need $\Omega(n\log n)$.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question to show us the specific reduction you have in mind.  Until you've done that, we can't really assess your argument.